# How can I use VSCode remote on a system where the home directory has noexec set

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use the VSCode remote extension. This installs and instance of the vscode-server under the home directory of my user, and then tries to start it.

This fails with a "permission denied" error.

The underlying reason is that the home directory is mounted with "noexec" which is a requirement where this machine is located. So I cannot execute anything from the home directory.

Now I have node.js installed, so there is a "node" executable that works, but vscode-server insists on using the node executable it ships itself.

Is there a way around this?